# YII2 REST API запрос

Tags: php, yii2, rest

Создал модель users. Запросом типа /users получаю всех юзеров В JSON.
Дело в том что id поле у меня называется "user_id" и при обращении к /user/1 я получаю 404
как быть?

Comment: Т.е вы хотите чтобы вам по запросу /user/1 возвращало json с данным пользователя у которого user_id = 1?

Comment: именно так!!!!!!

Comment: А у Вас есть действие в контроллере для этих целей? Покажите код который у Вас есть.

Comment: <?php

namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Users';
}

Comment: А правило в конфигурацию  для urlManager добавили?

Comment: Может пользователя в таким id в базе нет?

Comment: Обычная для rest конфигурация.
Если в модели и mysql я все поменяю на id, вместо user_id.
Все данные приходят без проблем.
Но мне нужно использовать именно user_id.

Comment: Ага теперь понял

Comment: Могу ли я как либо переопределить в контроллере. 
Мол, когда приходит (1) в запросе user/1, он вытягивает id из поля user_id

Comment: Получается он по умолчанию ищет поле ID. Но так как его нет, я получаю  404

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44530/discussion-between-mr-music-and-kison).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вашу проблему можно решить путем переопределения действия View.

**Не проверял но должно работать )**

```
class UserController extends ActiveController {
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Users';

    public function actions() {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['view']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionView($id){
        return User::findOne(['user_id' => $id]);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У модели Users вы можете указать маппинг для возвращаемых полей.

```
public function fields() {
    return [
       'user_id'=>'id'
    ];
}
```

А если модель у вас имплементится от IdentityInterface, то у него есть метод

```
public function getId() {
    return $this->user_id;
}
```

А вообще оно должно работать и понять само из схемы БД. Что user_id, это primaryKey, и поиск производить по нему. Предположу что вы что-то намудрили в коде или структуре базы.

Вот рабочий пример

Запрос

> /rest/client/1

Конфиг

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'pluralize' => false,
            'controller' => [
                'rest/client',
            ],
        ],
    ]
]
```

Контроллер

```
class ClientController extends Controller {
    public $modelClass = 'backend\modules\rest\models\Client';
}
```

Модель

```
class Client extends ActiveRecord {

public function fields() {
    return [
        'client_id',
        'name',
    ];
}
```

}

Таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
    `client_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `type_of_company` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status_enum` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `state_enum` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `added_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `u_client_name` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```